# gdal2tiles.py Only Creating Images for Max Zoom

Tags: gdal, gdalwarp, gdal2tiles

I set off some tasks running `gdal2tiles.py` for certain rasters with a zoom range of 8-20. To my dismay I return the next day to find only images for zoom level 20 have been created. I understand that this is a big range, but I don't think this should be a problem.

The command to generate images:
`gdal2tiles.py warped_file.tif output_dir --s_srs 'EPSG:4326' --zoom=8-20 --processes=3 --exclude`

The warped file is produced by this command:
`gdalwarp -s_srs 'EPSG:27700' -t_srs 'EPSG:4326' file.tif warped_file.tif`

Is there a reason why only zoom level 20 was created?

gdalinfo:

```
Size is 29404, 36007
Coordinate System is:
GEOGCRS["WGS 84",
    DATUM["World Geodetic System 1984",
        ELLIPSOID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]]],
    PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
        ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
    CS[ellipsoidal,2],
        AXIS["geodetic latitude (Lat)",north,
            ORDER[1],
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
        AXIS["geodetic longitude (Lon)",east,
            ORDER[2],
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
    ID["EPSG",4326]]
Data axis to CRS axis mapping: 2,1
Origin = (-2.030342225189838,51.716732655211317)
Pixel Size = (0.000051188440515,-0.000051188440515)
Metadata:
  AREA_OR_POINT=Area
  TIFFTAG_SOFTWARE=GRASS GIS 7.8.5 with GDAL 3.1.4
Image Structure Metadata:
  COMPRESSION=DEFLATE
  INTERLEAVE=BAND
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  (  -2.0303422,  51.7167327) (  2d 1'49.23"W, 51d43' 0.24"N)
Lower Left  (  -2.0303422,  49.8735905) (  2d 1'49.23"W, 49d52'24.93"N)
Upper Right (  -0.5251973,  51.7167327) (  0d31'30.71"W, 51d43' 0.24"N)
Lower Right (  -0.5251973,  49.8735905) (  0d31'30.71"W, 49d52'24.93"N)
Center      (  -1.2777698,  50.7951616) (  1d16'39.97"W, 50d47'42.58"N)
```

Comment: Your command looks good to me. Test it with a small image and you can see the result next minute.

Comment: @user30184, yea I have done that and it's been fine.. But I haven't done it on the output of the warp command before, so I suspect it is that which is causing the problem

Comment: Then warp a small image and test. However, lower zoom level tiles are built up from higher level base tiles (four tiles combined into one and resampled to bigger pixel size) and projection should not matter at this stage.

Comment: What is the latitude/longitude extent of file.tif? There are 1.1 trillion level 20 tiles if it covers the whole world

Comment: I have added the result of gdalinfo now - @BarryCarter. It is for a 100km2 grid of the UK only

Comment: That actually doesn't look too bad. You can watch the directories and see how fast it's creating tiles to perhaps understand how much of level 20 you got? Also, make sure the tile numbers you're getting are reasonable: gdal might be doing something weird